# Alternative to dokku for RPM based linux

Tags: linux, centos-7

I have found this project that emulates [Heroku hosting](http://heroku.com/) on local PC - [dokku](https://github.com/dokku/dokku). Is there any analogs of it for RPM based linux distributions?

UPD: this is my company requirements for this mini-PaaS:

1. it can be installed on RPM based Linux machine
2. we can deploy application in the similar way as heroku - `git push`
3. It do not requires top perfomance - there is about 4-5 micro services, 1 redis database, 1 mongo database, and about 100 clients for them.

Comment: dokku claims to work on rpm-based distributions.  It is not distributed as an rpm, but that doesn't keep it from getting installed.  So if you can run what you want why do want an analog?

Comment: i haven't tried it on RPM based disto before, in README.md they claim it required `A fresh VM running Ubuntu 14.04 x64`. I'll try it, thanks!

Comment: https://packagecloud.io/dokku/dokku/install has install docs for "deb", "rpm", "python",  and "gem".

Comment: Chicks, unfortunately it seems that http://packagecloud.io/dokku/dokku/install do not have binaries for RPM based distros

Comment: It looks like their script sets up a repo from where you can install packages.  Did that not work for you?

Comment: yes, it set repo, but `dnf install dokku` or `dnf install dokku_dokku` does nothing like there is no things to be installed...

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the only one that comes to my mind is [openshift](https://www.openshift.com/), but is is not as simple as dokku. You can use it directly from docker or install it manually in many nodes. It is developed by red hat, It has an open source version (openshift origin), an enterprise version and an online hosted version.

Answer (score 1):

Dokku Maintainer here:

We don't currently have RPM packages, nor any real plans to do so. None of the maintainers run RPM-based distributions, though we're not opposed to supporting them. As far as I know, there are a few places where we install packages from the OS repository, and it should be possible to find alternatives for those such that source-based installation works. This is how our experimental SUSE-support works, and we'd be happy to take any patches for this.

We currently officially support Debian 8.2+ and Ubuntu 14.04+ systems, so anything with systemd or upstart as it's init system will work fine. If you'd like to create an `rpm.mk` which has make targets for building RPM packages for `herokuish`, `sshcommand`, `plugn`, and `dokku`, that would also allow us to build official packages for that system.

The other option is a dockerfile-based deploy of dokku, which is currently being worked on in [#1076](https://github.com/dokku/dokku/issues/1076). I'm not sure when that will land in master, as there hasn't been any movement outside of my own in a few months.

All that said, given your company's requirements, perhaps [openshift](https://www.openshift.com/) is your current best bet? [Here is a list](https://github.com/veggiemonk/awesome-docker#local-container-manager) of container managers you can use, one of which may also be sufficient for your needs.

If you'd like to sponsor the work, I'd also be glad to prioritize RPM support. You can contact me at the email in my [github account](https://github.com/josegonzalez).